# Eigenbundles of a vector bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, representation-theory

Let $ X $ be a scheme, $ \mathcal{E} $ a locally free sheaf on $ X $ and $ G $ a finite group acting on $ \mathcal{E} $ as endomorphisms (which are necessarily automorphisms) of it. For any character $ \chi $, define $ \mathcal{E}^{\chi} $ as the subsheaf of $ \mathcal{E} $ on sections of which, each $ g \in G $ acts as scalar multiplication by $ \chi(g) $.

I would like a reference to a proof or a proof of the following result:

Each $ \mathcal{E}^{\chi} $ is locally free and $ \mathcal{E} = \bigoplus_{\chi} \mathcal{E}^{\chi} $ where the sum ranges over all the characters of $ G $.

Comment: This is not even true if $X = \text{Spec } k$ is the spectrum of a field without more hypotheses. Even in this restricted setting, where you are just asking about vector spaces, $G$ must be abelian and $k$ must have characteristic not dividing $|G|$ and enough roots of unity.

Comment: I forgot to say that my scheme was over the complex numbers, as the default case for me in algebraic geometry. Thanks for the point.

Comment: You still need to either assume that $G$ is abelian or you need to talk about isotypic components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct version is the decomposition into the direct sum of isotypical components, and it works under the assumption that some algebraic numbers belong to the ring of functions on $X$.

To obtain such a decomposition first consider the group algebra $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ and the decomposition of the unit of this algebra into the sum of idempotents corresponding to isomorphism classes of representations of $G$. The coefficients of these idempotents are algebraic numbers with denominators dividing $N$, the order of the group. So, if $\mathcal{O}_X$ contains all these coefficients (e.g., if $X$ is a scheme over the field of algebraic numbers), you can act by these idempotents on you vector bundle, and get the required decomposition.

Comment: Of course! Thanks for pointing this, I edited the answer accordingly.